# Create ApproxTime in Python

Tags: python

For my  exercise, i had facing a  problem of how to create a function

Write a function called approxTime which takes two integers as input: hour an integer between 1 and 12; and minute an integer between 0 and 59. The function should print the time to the nearest quarter
hour. Here are some examples:

```
>>> approxTime(3, 18)
The time is about quarter past three

>>> approxTime(3, 28)
The time is about half past three

>>> approxTime(8,50)
The time is about quarter to nine

>>> approxTime(8,55)
The time is about nine o’clock
```

Is there any hins how to do it?

I had did it in other way:

```
def approxTimehour(h):
        try:
            Hour = int(h)
        except:
            print("This is not a integer, please try again")
            return(None)
        if h<1:
            print("You cannot input Hour under 1")
            return(None)
        if h>12:
            print ("You cannot input Hour over 12")
            return(None)
        return Hour

def approxTimeMin(m):
        try:
            Minute = int(m)
        except:
            print("This is not a integer, please try again")
            return(None)
        if m<0:
            print("You cannot input Minute under 0")
            return(None)
        if m>59:
            print ("You cannot input Minute over 59")
            return(None)
        return Minute


PT1 = None
while PT1==None:
    h = int(input("Please input the hour (1-12):  "))
    PT1 = approxTimehour(h)

print("")

PT2 = None
while PT2==None:
    m = int(input("Please input the Minute (1-59):  "))
    PT2 = approxTimeMin(m)

print("The time is",h,":",m)

if m<15:
    print ("The time is ",h,"o'clock")
elif m>=15 and m<26:
    print ("The time is about quarter past",h)
elif m>25 and m<36:
    print ("The time is about half past",h)
elif m>35 and m<51:
    print ("The time is about quarter to",h+1)
elif m>50 and m<60:
    print ("The time is about",h+1,"o'clock")
```

And I want to know how to do in other way

Comment: How would you approach this if you had to do this by hand? Write out that logic first. The programming part will be translating the logic into code.

Comment: These kinds of questions are generally considered too broad/opinion based in scope for SO. I suggest you try something and ask specific questions when you run into an issue.

Comment: maybe check this out: http://pythonfiddle.com/time-word/ or https://sukhbinder.wordpress.com/2013/12/29/time-in-words-with-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Less of a hint more of a solution:

```
def approxTime(hours,minutes):
    if hours>12 or hours<0:
        return "Function error, hour value outside range"
    if minutes>59 or minutes<0:
        return "Function error, minute value outside range"
    nums = {0:"twelve",1:"one",2:"two",
            3:"three",4:"four",5:"five",6:"six",
            7:"seven",8:"eight",9:"nine",10:"ten",
            11:"eleven",12:"twelve"}
    if hours==12:
        hours = 0
    if minutes>0 and minutes <8 :
        return "The time is about "+nums[hours]
    elif minutes>=8 and minutes<23:
        return "The time is about quarter past "+nums[hours]
    elif minutes>=23 and minutes<38:
        return "The time is about half past "+nums[hours]
    elif minutes>=38 and minutes<53:
        return "The time is about quarter to "+nums[hours+1]
    else:
        return "The time is about "+nums[hours+1]
```

Comment: thanks for sharing, but I want hints not an answer. Want to learn more :)

Answer (score 1):

Another good way of determining which time you're closet too (0, 15, 30, 45, 60 [o' clock, quarter past, half past, quarter to, o' clock]) is to use `min` to determine the closest value:

```
closest = min([0, 15, 30, 45, 60], key=lambda x:abs(x-minute))
```

From here, you should do two things:

1. Determine whether you need to add an hour (for 45 and 60), since these are rounded up).
2. Parse the numbers to text, which can easily be done using dicts:

   ```
   hours_text = {0:"zero",1:"one",2:"two",3:"three",4:"four",5:"five",6:"six",7:"seven",8:"eight",9:"nine",10:"ten",11:"eleven",12:"twelve"}
   closest_text = {0: "o' clock", 15:"quarter past", 30: "half past", 45: "quarter to", 60: "o' clock"}
   ```

With this method I can write the function in 10 lines. [Here](https://gist.github.com/lutrasdebtra/c0924df885f6014ae8e51140cca445c0) it is if you're interested (didn't want to post it directly so you can try it yourself).